# Stuck with MD5, is there a way to make it any more secure?

Tags: encryption, passwords, md5

The site I'm working on right now uses a third-party billing company that handles user sign-ups, so all user names and passwords are entered in the biller's site, then the biller writes the username and the user's now encrypted password to a 'members' database on our server.

The problem is that the biller (and many of them, from what I gather) encrypts the passwords with MD5 which I have read over and over is NOT secure. But, as the encryption is handled at the biller's end, and they are only offering MD5, I wanted to know if there was anything I could do on my end to make the passwords more secure?

As I'm writing this, I'm thinking that, 'If the biller is encrypting the passwords, there's probably no way for me to add more security' because part of the biller's job is to handle member issues such as lost passwords and other issues.

So...is there a way to add more security to the passwords the biller stores in our DB or do we just take our chances with what we all know is an unsafe standard? We're stuck with this biller for the short term, and what's worse, I contacted another biller who is very well known and they use MD5 as well.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `MD5` is not encryption - it's hashing.

Comment: You say, the biller hashes the password, but stores the hash in your database. Does the biller also read this hashed password back for authentication, or why is it stored in your database? Does the biller maintain it's own database as well?

Comment: @martinstoeckli My apologies for replying so late. The biller handles the initial transaction with each subscriber. Then their username and PW are stored in a database on my server. They offer this method or .htaccess which has its own issues. They do not maintain or store usernames and PWs at their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not a lot you can do about the biller at this stage.  It's difficult to know what threats you're trying to mitigate against.  If you're worried about the communication between the biller and your machines being monitored then SSL or SSH should help with that.  If you're worried about an attacker breaking into your database and stealing passwords, then using a different scheme to store the passwords in will help.

You can either stick with MD5 and add a salt.  Please check that your biller is salting their passwords, if they're not you really need to get rid of them.  They're database will be vulnerable to [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) lookups.

> A rainbow table is a precomputed table for reversing cryptographic hash functions, usually for cracking password hashes

You could take the MD5s you receive and use a better password hashing algorithm (assuming you don't need to keep the original MD5).  One example is [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).  Note that SHA1, SHA-256, etc. whilst better hashing algorithms are not that great at password hashing.  The reason is that SHA is designed to be fast.  You want password hashing to be relatively slow.  For legitimate users, waiting 20ms for a correct password validation is no time at all, but for an attacker it *drastically* reduces their ability to brute force a password.

> bcrypt is a key derivation function for passwords designed by Niels Provos and David Mazières, based on the Blowfish cipher, and presented at USENIX in 1999.[1] Besides incorporating a salt to protect against rainbow table attacks, bcrypt is an adaptive function: over time, the iteration count can be increased to make it slower, so it remains resistant to brute-force search attacks even with increasing computation power.

Essentially, bcrypt has a good hashing algorithm, requires a salt and lets you specify the number of times the hashing algorithm is run on it.  You could, for example, start off with 100 rounds.  In two years time when computing power has increased you can then increase that to 150.

Comment: My apology for the late reply. The biller takes the username and PW when a person subscribes to the website then they use MD5 to hash the PW and this info is stored in a database on my server. If I understand correctly, you want to know if they use a salt in conjunction with the MD5, correct? I'm asking so that I make sure I ask the biller the right questions. Many thanks!

Comment: Ideally they should be using the salt with the password and hashing that.  A salt is a string randomly chosen on the server to append onto the password before hashing.  E.g. `hash = MD5( salt + password )`  You would then have to store the hash and the salt in the database.  Note that salts only prevent rainbow table lookups against hashes (use a different salt for each user).  If they're not giving you a salt along with the hash then they're not salting the password.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on your requirements, but it sounds like you don't have to store MD5s in your database.  You could store `bcrypt(md5Hash)`.  Then validating a user is the exact same operation.  Your database then has a reasonably secure store of password hashes.  This assumes your biller will only ever ask if an MD5 is valid or not.  Hopefully the biller is not storing the MD5 hashes!

Comment: They place a script in a folder on my server that apparently compares the user's PW to the hashed PW in my database. But the hashed PWs are stored in my database. I have decided to move forward with SSL and am having a security certificate for this particular domain installed. It is frightening to see that this biller...and others only offer MD5 hashing and .htaccess as the only options. I sincerely appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Md5 is technically a hasing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. The difference being that you cannot unhash a a hashed string (in theory, md5 is weak because this was proven false). You can undo encrypting if you have the appropriate key.

What is your biggest concern? Are you worried about someone intercepting the passwords as they travel between you and the biller or are you worried about someone opening the database?

If you are worried about someone breaking into your database and getting your table with passwords, then you can definitely improve the security. You could encrypt the entries before you persist them using a modern algorithm with your own private key. Don't store the key with the server and unencrypt when pulling out of the database before using the md5 value.

You could also, just hash the md5 value they give you (and use a salt) with some modern strong hashing algorithm. This means that if anyone gets your table, they will have to unhash your hash, then unhash the md5. Presumably you would use a strong hash and the first step would be impossible. As always, be careful with security as you most certainly should write something yourself, you will have bugs!